# A direct sum involving a linear map, null and a span.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that $V = \operatorname{Null}\phi\oplus U$

Suppose that $\phi \in \mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$ and $u \in V$ is not in $\operatorname{Null}\phi$.

Let $U= \operatorname{Span}(u)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need

$V = \ker \phi \oplus \text{span}(\{ u \}); \tag 0$

I use the notation

$\ker \phi = \text{Null} \; \phi; \tag 1$

given that

$u \notin \ker \phi; \tag 2$

we have

$0 \ne \phi(u) \in \Bbb F; \tag 3$

we may thus define

$v = \dfrac{1}{\phi(u)}u; \tag 4$

then

$\phi(v) = \dfrac{1}{\phi(u)}\phi(u) = 1; \tag 5$

now for $y \in V$ we have

$\phi(y - \phi(y)v) = \phi(y) - \phi(y) \phi(v) = \phi(y) - \phi(y) = 0; \tag 6$

that is,

$y - \phi(y)v \in \ker \phi, \tag 7$

and clearly

$\phi(y) v \in \text{span}(\{v\}) = \text{span}(\{u\}) \tag 8$

in light of (4); we have thus shown that every $y \in V$ may be written in the form

$y = y - \phi(y) v + \phi(y)v \in \ker \phi + \text{span}(\{u\}); \tag 9$

to complete the establishment of (0), we merely need to show that

$\ker \phi \cap \text{span}(\{u\}) = \{0\}; \tag{10}$

but if

$z \in \ker \phi \cap \text{span}(\{u\}), \tag{11}$

then

$z \in \ker \phi, \tag{12}$

that is,

$\phi(z) = 0; \tag{13}$

also,

$z \in \text{span}(\{u\}) \Longrightarrow \exists \beta \in \Bbb F, \; z = \beta u; \tag{14}$

for such $z$, by (13),

$\beta \phi(u) = \phi(\beta u) = \phi(z) = 0, \tag{14}$

thus (3) forces

$\beta = 0; \tag{15}$

therefore

$z = \beta u = 0; \tag{16}$

hence (10) and, finally, (0) are validated.